# How much stone should we want?

Tags: probability

Let's assume we have stones and $1$ bucket. We will put first stone to this bucket and win a new bucket. In the next move, we will randomly put a stone. If we put stone to the first bucket we will continue, if we put stone to second bucket we will have a new bucket. They will give us $x$ stones in the beginning. If we can win the $n^{th}$ bucket we will win. What should $x$ be, at least, for winning more often?

Thanks for any help. Please don't hesitate to correct my English mistakes.

Comment: Let me be sure that I understand: you want to know the smallest $x$ such that the probability of winning at least $n$ buckets is greater than $\frac12$?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the smallest $x$ such that the probability of winning $n$ buckets is greater than 1/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, is it when a person has $n$ buckets with him, then probability of winning another bucket in next round is $\frac{1}{n}$? If so, then then here is some bound.

__

Let random variable $X_n$ denote the number of throws required to win $n$ buckets. Now, $X_n > K$ means that in the first $K$ throws he did not win $n$ buckets, and vice versa. Thus,

$$Prob[X_n > K]=Prob[\text{he does not win $n$ buckets in $K$ throws}]$$

__

We will show that for $K=n(n-1)$ this probability is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

__

Let $Y_k$ denote the number of throws required to win another bucket when a person has $k$ buckets with him. If he has $k$ buckets with him then probability of winning another one is $p_k=\frac{1}{k}$. Thus, $E(Y_k)=\frac{1}{p_k}=k$.

Now $X_n=Y_1 + y_2 + ... + Y_{n-1}$. So, by linearity of expectation we get

$$E(X_n)=E(Y_1) + E(y_2) + ... + E(Y_{n-1}) = 1+2+...+(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

By Markov inequality we have,

$$Prob[X_n \geq n(n-1)] \leq \frac{E(X_n)}{n(n-1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus,

$$Prob[\text{he does not win $n$ buckets in $K$ throws}] \leq \frac{1}{2}$$